# Calculate angular frequency of oscillation of a SHO if potential is given

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

Is it possible to calculate the angular frequency or time  period of oscillation from only potential expression which consists of two variables x and y?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Maybe you want to give additional details on the difficulty you have in doing this in your specific case?

Comment: It will not be harmonic motion (as per title) unless the potential is linear though, or do you mean just periodic?

Comment: If I ask that then someone will reply this is not your homework problem solving class. tag tgat or that blah bblah blah etc etc. Please consider a two variable function as you wish, solve it and upload it here, please.

Comment: -1 for requesting others to solve your problem.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero it's a parabolic potential for SHM, linear force.

Comment: @CDCM I don't think so else it's completely trivial.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero SHM potential is $\propto x^2$, giving $F\propto -x$.  Linear potential would give $F=0$.  I feel we've probably misunderstood what the other was saying at some point, since none of this is rocket science

Comment: @CDCM agreed.  If this is really SHM then it's trivial.  I thought this was about periodic motion in a general potential but the OP steadfastly refuses to provide details.

Comment: You need the mass of the object as well. The problem as currently posed is too ill defined to deserve an answer in this site - show your thinking and tell us what're you are stumped. You say "SHO" but imply arbitrary potential? Voting to close as "unclear" for now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.  If you're perhaps used to working with forces, remember that
$$F=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}.$$

Then we see that with $F=-kx$, $U=\frac{1}{2}k x^2$.  Hence by this identification, and using the result $\omega=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$, you can find your answer.

Comment: If potential is a two variable function then is it possible to find frequency?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Start by writing the equation, $$m\ddot{\textbf{r}}=-\nabla U$$  Then split it into components and go from there.

Comment: So, there are two frequency along two coordinate axis, say x and y.